# How to concatenate npm command with shell command

Tags: javascript, git, shell, npm

I have a shell script which gives the commit hash and I want to run `npm version` and would like to concatenate with the hash.

So putting the shell command in js file and running with node works. Since the command is very short I want to run inline.

This works

```js
npm --no-git-tag-version version $(node bump.js)
```

But would like to run in one line

`npm --no-git-tag-version version`+ `git rev-parse --short HEAD`

Here is my `bump.js` file

```js
const shell = require('shelljs');
const { version } = require('../package.json');

if (!shell.which('git')) {
  shell.echo('Sorry, this script requires git');
  shell.exit(1);
}

// npm --no-git-tag-version version $(node config/bump.js)
// Ex: npm --no-git-tag-version version  "10.1.6-develop-80a3053"

let commitHash = '';
if (commitHash = shell.exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD', { silent: true })) {
  // Getting the base version from package.json
  const baseVersion = version.match(/[\d+]{1,}\.[\d+]{1,}\.[\d+]{1,}/)[0];

  // Concatenating base-version with develop-commit-hash
  const hashedVersion = `${baseVersion}-develop-${commitHash}`;
  shell.echo(`npm --no-git-tag-version version ${hashedVersion}`, { silent: true });

}

shell.exit(0);
```

Comment: And what is stopping you please?

Comment: Basically I want to run `npm --no-git-tag-version version "10.1.6-develop-06678370"` where `10.1.6` is the version from package.json and `06678370` is the shorthand commit hash retrieved from the command `git rev-parse --short HEAD`. So is there any way to run them in online without writing `bump.js` file with `shelljs` library

Comment: Please clarify what *""package.json"* is and how you get "10.1.6" out of it.

Comment: I have added the code for `bump.js` the package.json will have `"version":"10.1.6-develop-80a3053"` or it could have just `"version": "10.1.6"` and script should suffix it with `-develop-80a3053` where `80a3053` the short hand of last git commit.